# prevent new window opening onsubmit=window.open

Tags: javascript, html

Just wondering is it possible to use `onSubmit="window.open('url')"` but instead of it opening a new tab , have it load on the current page.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the target `_self` to open the page in the same window. You would return `false` from the event to keep the form from posting:

```
onsubmit="window.open('url','_self');return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

For that case you can try this :
`onSubmit="window.location.href='url';return false;"`

Its better though to avoid inline JavaScript, and try to keep JavaScript separated from html.